# How to set a function attribute to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, function, attributes, inline

I have a function:

```
void add(double& input) __attribute__((always_inline));
void add(double& input){
    input += 10;
}
```

I want to use a pointer to point to this function.

```
void (* func)(double& input)
```

I want to know where to put `__attribute__((always_inline))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's impossible. Think about it: the function pointer can be dynamically changed to point to different things. Would you have the program somehow recompile itself for the new function whenever you assign to it?

Comment: So, If I want to use a function pointer as a line function, what can I do without setting compiler optimize?

Comment: If you have a function pointer, it has to point to a function - you can't have an inline copy at the point you use the function pointer (the compiler can't tell what function the pointer is going to be pointing at).